# How do I authenticate against Azure Active Directory from my client app?

Tags: web-services, azure, claims-based-identity, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I am building a small client application in C#. I am trying to call a web service that is secured using Azure Active Directory.

How do I get a token from Azure Active Directory for use when calling the web service?

Answer (score 1):

The [AzureADSamples GitHub repo](https://github.com/AzureADSamples) should have everything you need.

Either the [NativeClient-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet) (if you're doing impersonation) or [NativeClient-Headless-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet) (if you're using a single application account) examples should be very close to what you're doing.